# Grouped item in uwp masterdetail control

Tags: c#, uwp, windows-community-toolkit

I am trying to adapt the MasterDetail control of the uwp community toolkit to group the elements in the main view and if it is possible to add a zoom in and zoom out as in a semantic view.

I come back after some implementation tests and unsuccessful experiments.
I check this code, sarting from the master/detail sample from the community toolkit, but I have an "Incorrect parameter" exception when navigate to the Master/Detail page.

```
    <Page.Resources>
    <!-- datatemplate -->
    <CollectionViewSource x:Name="grpStatus" IsSourceGrouped="true" Source="{x:Bind Path=ViewModel.GrpSource}" ItemsPath="Items"/>

    <DataTemplate x:Key="ZoomedInGroupHeaderTemplate" x:DataType="model:GrpItemsList">
        <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind Path=GrpName}" FontSize="20" />
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="ZoomedOutHeaderTemplate" x:DataType="model:GrpItemsList">
        <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind Path=GrpName}" FontSize="15" />
    </DataTemplate>

    <!-- restyling -->
    <Style TargetType="ListView">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <!-- Control template for listView -->
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListView">
                    <SemanticZoom>
                        <SemanticZoom.ZoomedInView>
                            <GridView ItemsSource="{Binding grpStatus.View}"
                                      ItemTemplate="{StaticResource itmTemplate}">
                                <GridView.GroupStyle>
                                    <GroupStyle HeaderTemplate="{StaticResource ZoomedInGroupHeaderTemplate}" />
                                </GridView.GroupStyle>
                            </GridView>
                        </SemanticZoom.ZoomedInView>
                        <SemanticZoom.ZoomedOutView>
                            <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding grpStatus.Source}"
                                      ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ZoomedOutHeaderTemplate}" />
                        </SemanticZoom.ZoomedOutView>
                    </SemanticZoom>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>

    <DataTemplate x:Key="itmTemplate" x:DataType="model:SampleOrder">
        ... sample default
    </DataTemplate>
...
</Page.Resources>
```

And in model/viewmodel

```
public class GrpItemsList
{
    public GrpItemsList(List<SampleOrder> objLst)
    {
        Items = new ObservableCollection<SampleOrder>(objLst);
    }
    public String GrpName { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<SampleOrder> Items { get; private set; }
}
```

in MasterDetailViewModel.cs

```
    ...
    public ObservableCollection<GrpItemsList> GrpSource { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<GrpItemsList>();

    public async Task LoadDataAsync(MasterDetailsViewState viewState)
    {
        var data = await SampleDataService.GetSampleModelDataAsync();

        GrpSource.Clear();
        GrpItemsList gItm = null;
        foreach(String sStat in data.Select(x => x.Status).Distinct())
        {
            gItm = new GrpItemsList(data.Where(x => x.Status == sStat).ToList());
            gItm.GrpName = sStat;
            GrpSource.Add(gItm);
        }
    }
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be accomplished by restyling the control and adding the SemanticZoom functionality [(docs)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/controls-and-patterns/semantic-zoom). You can find the default [style for the MasterDetailsView](https://github.com/Microsoft/UWPCommunityToolkit/blob/master/Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Controls/MasterDetailsView/MasterDetailsView.xaml) on GitHub. Where the [ListView is currently](https://github.com/Microsoft/UWPCommunityToolkit/blob/master/Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Controls/MasterDetailsView/MasterDetailsView.xaml#L39-L47), make the appropriate changes for zooming as noted in the documentation link

Comment: Thx for answer.

I am relatively new in this type of development and I am not sure to understand what is "restyling" at the moment, and how to replace a listview with a semantic view but I search and I come back if necessary.
If you have some good pointers / link on this topic it would be great.